# How to style images in highcharts flags?

Tags: javascript, css, image, highcharts, flags

In my chart, I show the user pictures for their comment date, so the users can read the comments in a tooltip using these icons. It seems like soundcloud charts. I did it using flags type and I set the shape variables as user picture url for each data item.

But I want to add also colorized border for each icons. I know, there is `lineWidth` and `lineColor` config in flags type but it doesn't work with images, it works only with default shapes `flag`, `circlepin` or `squarepin`.

I tried to use shape as `flag` and to add user images as background image, but It doesn't work.

[image]

Comment: You have to show your HTML at least..

Comment: You can try to catch load/redraw chart events and then use renderer to add custom images. (http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#Renderer.image)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In SVG you can not set border for the images, you need to create rect around the image: http://jsfiddle.net/xuL76rkL/1/

For example you can use `load` and `redraw` events to manage those rects, code:

```
var H = Highcharts;
function drawBorder() {
    var chart = this;

    H.each(chart.series[1].points, function(p) {
        var bbox,
            rect,
            fontSize = 13, // it's used as default font size offet, even for the images
            dim = 32; //width and height for the image
        if(p.graphic) {
            if(p.rectangle) {
                p.rectangle.destroy();   
            }
            bbox = p.graphic.getBBox();
            rect = chart.renderer.rect(p.plotX - dim/2, p.plotY - dim/2 - fontSize, dim, dim).attr({
                "stroke": "black",
                "stroke-width": 2,
                "fill": "transparent"
            }).add(chart.series[1].markerGroup);
            p.rectangle = rect;
        }
    });
}


$('#container').highcharts('StockChart', {

    chart: {
        events: {
            load: drawBorder,
            redraw: drawBorder  
        }
    },
    ...
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You can set an image with the shape option:

Example: `shape: "url(/assets/my_image.svg)"`

Documentation available here: https://api.highcharts.com/highstock/series.flags.shape